# Eclipse haml/sass editing + html /css generation

Tags: text-editor, haml, sass, aptana, staticmatic

I've been playing with haml and sass and generating a flat site with staticmatic from the command line.

Has anyone been using an ide for this?

I have the Apatana studio (RadRails) plugin installed and it has haml & sass highlighting out of the box. For this site I just want a lightweight script project (no rails).

What type of project would I use, and how would i add something so i could for example, right click the project folder in order to run

staticmatic build [my-project]

(or other) to generate the site from the haml + sass?

I like staticmatic as I can use ruby libraries as helpers.

Happy to take suggestions about any editor. But i am also keen to stick with one editor for everything. (also WTB auto complete).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can run rake tasks from the RadRails IDE, though I didn't manage to get it work. Ruby is probably right choice for the project type. I don't like IDEs because they complicate and slow things down. So my choice is normally Textmate + terminal.

Take a look at Rakefile in this project: https://github.com/adamstac/staticmatic-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

This isn't *exactly* what you're asking for...but [take a look at a tiny script that I wrote](http://github.com/nchase/swatch). It will watch directories of your choosing for changes in SCSS and HAML and compile them to html and css. You could make some minor edits to watch.rb if desired, run this in a terminal, and have the site generated without even having to run a command.

PS - if you decide to try this out, you'll need the fssm gem from github or [rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org/gems/fssm).

Answer (score 0):

A Ruby or Web project type would be most fitting, though I don't think it would matter which in this case.

You can achieve custom commands a number of ways...

1. You can write up a Rake task in the project Rakefile as Heikki suggested, and then right click and use the Rake menu (as of Studio 3.0.2) to launch that task, or run it inside the embedded Terminal view.
2. You can write/edit a custom ruble and add a command for launching staticmatic. See http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Executing+an+External+Command
3. You can go the Eclipse route and create an "External Tool Launch configuration" under *Run > External Tools. External Tools configuration... > Program*. There you can set up a launch to execute some program (say the ruby interpreter or staticmatic script itself) and pass in the argument. Then you can use the run drop-down menu.